# Eclipse find in specific files

Tags: php, eclipse

Is it possible to define in witch files inside a project I want to make my search?

Meaning, if I'm searching for a specific variable, I want it to search **only** in .php and .js files. I do not want eclipse to waste my time but searching it inside image or pdf files etc.

So, can this be done? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an editor window is focused press Ctrl+H (or from the main menu, click Search and then Search...). Activate the 'File Search' tab if it is not active. In the 'File name patterns' field you can enter a comma separated list with wild cards. E.g. the value "*.php, *.js" will search in files with extension php or js.

Comment: Thanx m8, I was looking for a field like that, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

In the menus:

```
Search -> File...
```

You can then enter containing text, as well as a pattern that file names have to match.

Note: Eclipse 4.2.0